# mysql update from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to update the MySQL table cp5sql from table spanish and am using the following statement in PhpMyadmin. The field names are correct, although a little different in each table.  The last part of the statement is limiting the update to word 'able' just for testing.

I get an error that something is wrong on line 2.

```
UPDATE cp5sql c
SET (Spanish_ID, Spanish_Type,Spanish_Uoffset,Spanish_Synset,Spanish_Word)=
(SELECT SID,type,offset,synset,word FROM spanish s
WHERE s.type=c.Type AND s.synset=c.synset AND c.Word ='able');
```

I have also tried:

```
UPDATE cp5sql
SET (Spanish_ID, Spanish_Type,Spanish_Uoffset,Spanish_Synset,Spanish_Word)=
(SELECT SID,type,offset,synset,word FROM spanish
WHERE spanish.type=cp5sql.Type AND spanish.synset=cp5sql.synset AND cp5sql.Word ='able');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a good guess, but it's actually an `UPDATE FROM` syntax.
Something like this:

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

Trying to make your example into this syntax would be something like:

```
UPDATE cp5sql c
SET Spanish_ID = SID, 
  Spanish_Type = type,
  Spanish_Uoffset = offset,
  Spanish_Synset = synset,
  Spanish_Word = word
FROM spanish s
WHERE s.type = c.Type
  AND s.synset = c.synset
  AND c.Word ='able';
```

Comment: Good alternative.  Thank you Pachonk.  I will run this when the other completes.  Should also be a good comparison for speed and such.

Comment: Depending on the indices and the way it joins together, one of the two might be drastically faster than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UPDATE JOIN`:

```
UPDATE cp5sql c
JOIN spanish s
ON s.type = c.Type AND s.synset = c.synset AND c.Word = 'able'
SET 
    c.Spanish_ID = s.SID,
    c.Spanish_Type = s.type,
    c.Spanish_Uoffset = s.offset,
    c.Spanish_Synset = s.synset,
    c.Spanish_Word = s.word;
```

Comment: Good answer, except it's a faster query to separate the static 'able' into a where clause at the end of the query.

Comment: Thank you Grant.  This got no errors and has been running about 15 mins.  Both are large files over 200k rows each, so I'm guessing the join takes a bit of time.

Comment: @user3522145 Because you have big data, running any query will take a bit of time, and here I think you have to explain this.